# How to build one to many relationship with different entities which have a composite key with Hibernate, JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to build entity classes for the following relationship. I want an entity ProductWiseCustomer which has a composite key. Those key also mapped with Product and Customer entities. How to achieve the purpose?

[image: Entity Relationship]

So far what I have done.

Product.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "product")
    public class Product {
        @Id
        private Long productId;
        private String productName;
        private Decimal productPrice;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = CustomerProductCompound.class)
        private Set<CustomerProductCompound> customerProductCompound;

        //Constructor
        //Setter-getter
    }
```

Customer.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "customerinfo")
    public class CustomerInfo {
        @Id

        private Long customerId;
        private String customerName;
        private Boolean isActive;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = CustomerProductCompound.class)
        private Set<CustomerProductCompound> customerProductCompound;

   //Constructor
   //Setter-getter
}
```

CustomerProductCompound.java

```
    @Embeddable
    public class CustomerProductCompound
   {

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
        private CustomerInfo customerInfo;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
        private Product product;

        //Constructor
        //Setter-getter
    }
```

While running the application getting the following error:

Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.auth.model.CustomerInfo.customerProductCompound[com.auth.model.CustomerProductCompound].

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a composite identifier with @EmbeddableId.

```
@Entity
public class ProductWiseCustomer {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductCustomerKey key;

}

@Embeddable
public class ProductCustomerKey {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Product product;
}
```

Please see the hibernate documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-aggregated

Answer (score 0):

`CustomerProductCompound` as you have defined just the primary key of `ProductWiseCustomer`. Your collections inside `CustomerInfo` and `Product` must contain `ProductWiseCustomer` items, not its key.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    private Long productId;
    private String productName;
    private Decimal productPrice;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ProductWiseCustomer> productWiseCustomers;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "customerinfo")
public class CustomerInfo {
    @Id

    private Long customerId;
    private String customerName;
    private Boolean isActive;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ProductWiseCustomer> productWiseCustomers;

}
```

Notice I added the `mappedBy` property in the annotations. It needs to point to the property name on the other side that refers to this object. The JPA name, not the SQL name. `targetEntity` is rarely necessary, and I've suggested `orphanRemoval`, so that if you remove one from the set, you don't have to manually delete it for it to go away.

As for the `ProductWiseCustomer`, you do need the same key as shown by Modular Coder

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductCustomerKey {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerId)
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
    private Product product;
}
```

But I recommend you use `@IdClass` instead of `@EmbeddedId`

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProductCustomerKey.class)
public class ProductWiseCustomer {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // should be lazy here
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerId)
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // should be lazy here
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
    private Product product;

    private OffsetDateTime createDate;
    private String remarks;
    // getters, setters
}
```